# Adding a ribbon to an existing non-ribbon mfc project - assert error in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, ribbon

Today I followed this tutorial
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2013/07/10/switching-between-cmfcribbonbar-based-ribbon-interface-and-cmfcmenubar-cmfctoolbar-based-interface-on-the-fly.aspx
and I got an error message. I've posted a comment to the tutorial. As far as I can see, it seems like m_hWnd is not a window, but I have no idea why :/

Comment: Please post the code snippet that you think causes the issue. Also add the error message you're seeing.

Comment: You are using a CWnd object that has never been created or is already destroyed. Look into the call stack, which part of your code cause this assert.

Comment: @Sorin 
This is the toggled breakpoint
_AFXWIN_INLINE CWnd* CWnd::GetParent() const
 { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return CWnd::FromHandle(::GetParent(m_hWnd)); }

The line that triggers it:
m_wndMenuBar.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);

And the message is "Debug Assertion Failed!".

Comment: @xMRi

> mfc100ud.dll!CWnd::GetParent()  Line 297 + 0x2d bytes C++

Comment: m_wndMenuBar.ShowPane(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE); //Here's the problem but I can't figure why. For some reason it won't seem to work :/

Comment: Than the Create function of m_wndMenuBar isn't when you call m_wndMenuBar.ShowPane!
What function uses m_wndMenuBar.ShowPane in this moment?

Comment: virtual void ShowPane(BOOL bShow, BOOL bDelay, BOOL bActivate); //That's all I could find. The same function works for m_wndRibbonBar.

Comment: And this: CMFCMenuBar hWnd=0x00000000

Answer (score 0):

If you did not

`m_wndMenuBar.Create(this)`

before ShowPane it is natural it is not working well. I think you are mixing Ribbon and menu functionality. I have in my hands a commercial application that has both of them, and it works well.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot - I've fixed already. But it was 3 or 4 months ago and I can't remember what I changed so it started working. It was a little bug like the one you pointed.